# How to save to local storage using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, local-storage

In Android, If I have the information I want to persist across sessions I know I can use `SharedPreferences` or create a **SQLite** database or even write a file to the device and read it in later.

Is there a way to save and restore data like this just using Flutter? Or would I need to write device-specific code for Android and iOS like in the [services example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/34e466f1fdb8ccb2e595c674385924817e788769/examples/hello_services)?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

There are a few options:

- Read and write files: https://flutter.io/reading-writing-files/
- SQLite via a Flutter plugin: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite
- SQLCipher via a Flutter plugin: https://github.com/drydart/flutter_sqlcipher
- SharedPreferences via a Flutter plugin: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/shared_preferences
- Localstore via a Flutter plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/localstore

Comment: I wrote a flutter service to access SQLite, see https://github.com/ripple182/FlutterSQLiteSample

Comment: is it posible if i use Room? what happen with ios if i use Room?

Comment: This seems to work better for Shared Preferences: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: New package https://github.com/lesnitsky/flutter_localstorage

Comment: In the options above, what is the recommended storage for storing authentication tokens (like access tokens, id tokens, etc.)?

Comment: I'd like to know what is the best option in localstorage and localstore. Is it same?

Comment: @Yster. Shared Preferences is working on iOS version?

Answer (score 96):

If you are in  a situation where you wanna save a small value that you wanna refer later, then you should store your data as key-value data using shared_preferences

- [Storing key-value data on disk](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/key-value/)

but if you want to store large data you should go with SQLITE

- [How to get Started with SQLITE in Flutter](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/how_to.md)

however you can always use firebase database which is available offline

- [how to add firebase to your flutter project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)
- [Firebase for Flutter Codelab from google](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/index.html)

Since we are talking about local storage you can always read and write files to the disk

- [Reading and Writing Files](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/)

Other solutions :

- [Simple Embedded Application Store database](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sembast)
- [A Flutter plugin to store data in secure storage](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_secure_storage)

Comment: how to decide when to use sqflite or firebase?

Comment: `sqflite` stores it only in the phone. `firebase` gets sync'ed in a central database where you can perform queries in your backend. `firebase` also makes easy synchronization between devices.

Comment: Please note that Firebase's Firestore defaults to 10MB and may be set to no less than 1MB and a max of 100MB. Pure offline access is not recommended. If you plan to use this as a local storage option only and the data is large, you may need to reconsider. 

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(long)

Comment: This should be preferred answer, because it simply explains where to look in different scenarios.

Answer (score 27):

A late answer but I hope it will help anyone visiting here later too..

I will provide categories to save and their respective best methods...

1. **Shared Preferences**
    Use this when storing simple values on storage e.g Color theme, app language, last scroll position(in reading apps).. these are simple settings that you would want to persist when the app restarts..
    You could, however, use this to store large things(Lists, Maps, Images) **but that would require serialization and deserialization**.. To learn more on this deserialization and serialization go [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5965747-data-persistence-on-flutter).
2. **Files**
    This helps a lot when you have data that is defined more by you for example log files, image files and maybe you want to export csv files.. I heard that this type of persistence can be washed by storage cleaners once disk runs out of space.. Am not sure as i have never seen it.. 
    This also can store almost anything but with the help of serialization and deserialization..
3. **Saving to a database**
    This is enormously helpful in data which is a bit complex. And I think this doesn't get washed up by disc cleaners as it is stored in *AppData*(for android)..
    In this, your data is stored in an SQLite database. Its plugin is [SQFLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite).
    Kinds of data that you might wanna put in here are like everything that can be represented by a database.

Answer (score 15):

You can use **shared preferences** from flutter's official plugins.
 https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/shared_preferences

It uses Shared Preferences for Android, NSUserDefaults for iOS.

Comment: Is this ideal for large databases?

Comment: @temp_ I don't know much about iOS. Shared Preferences on Android, however, are definitively not suited for large database. They are written as plain xml files to the file system, and read from file system if requested. They are mainly used for storing app preferences and similar things.

Comment: This seems to work better for Shared Preferences: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Answer (score 14):

You can use **[Localstorage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage)**

```
flutter pub add localstorage
```

**1-** Add dependency to `pubspec.yaml` ([**Change the version based on the last**](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage/versions))

```
dependencies:
  ...
  localstorage: ^4.0.0+1
```

**2-** Then run the following command

```
flutter packages get
```

**3-**  import the localstorage :

```
import 'package:localstorage/localstorage.dart';
```

**4-** create an instance

```
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage('localstorage_app');
  ...
}
```

**Add** item to lcoalstorage :

```
void addItemsToLocalStorage() {
  storage.setItem('name', 'Abolfazl');
  storage.setItem('family', 'Roshanzamir');

  final info = json.encode({'name': 'Darush', 'family': 'Roshanzami'});
  storage.setItem('info', info);
}
```

**Get** an item from lcoalstorage:

```
void getitemFromLocalStorage() {
  final name = storage.getItem('name'); // Abolfazl
  final family = storage.getItem('family'); // Roshanzamir
  
  Map<String, dynamic> info = json.decode(storage.getItem('info'));
  final info_name=info['name'];
  final info_family=info['family'];
}
```

**Delete** an item from localstorage :

```
void removeItemFromLocalStorage() {
  storage.deleteItem('name');
  storage.deleteItem('family');
  storage.deleteItem('info');
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this library, but seems like this is a way to store files in JSON with unique key.  This looks a bit like NoSQL, but it's lack of all the DB operations such as query and update.  that's the difference compare with sqllite.

Comment: How to list view all the items which saved in the json file?

Answer (score 13):

If you need to store just simple values like API token or login data (not passwords!), here is what I used:

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

asyncFunc() async { // Async func to handle Futures easier; or use Future.then
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
...

// Set
prefs.setString('apiToken', token);

// Get
String token = prefs.getString('apiToken');

// Remove
prefs.remove('apiToken');
```

Don't forget to add `shared_preferences` dependency in your pubspec.yaml (preserve spacing format):

```yaml
dependencies:

  shared_preferences: any
```

Answer (score 8):

## There are a few options:

#### Moor: Persistence library for Dart

- https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter

#### Read and Write file

- https://flutter.io/reading-writing-files/

#### Shared preferences plugin for flutter

- https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

#### SQlite for flutter

- https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Comment: Moor is still experimental on Web. You can't write files on Web. Shared preferences does not guarantee writes. SQlite only supports mobile. None of these are cross platform options.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same, simple local storage but also with a reasonable level of security. The two solutions I've found that make the most sense are [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) (as mentioned by [Raouf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50849802/2860309)) for the small stuff, and [hive](https://github.com/hivedb/hive) for larger datasets.

Answer (score 3):

Hive (https://pub.dev/packages/hive) is very fast and flexible solution. But if you have experience with SQL; you can use SqfLite packages (https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

Answer (score 2):

I think If you are going to store large amount of data in local storage you can use sqflite library. It is very easy to setup and I have personally used for some test project and it works fine.

https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite 
This a tutorial - https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-bookshelf-app-part-2-personal-notes-and-database-integration-a3b47a84c57

If you want to store data in cloud you can use firebase. It is solid service provide by google.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup