# How to restore the current Route and the Route stack when the app is paused/resumed?

Tags: flutter

Say I have a Flutter TODO app in with three routes:

- `Home`, which shows all TODO item summaries;
- `TODO details`, which shows a TODO item details when the user taps on an item in the `Home` screen.
- `Edit TODO details`, a **popup** route that partially covers the screen when the user taps "edit" on the `TODO details` screen.

This means that at some point the `Route` stack could be:

- [`Edit TODO details`] (Current)
- [`TODO details`]
- [`Home`]

How can I make it so that when the OS eventually paused the app, I can save this stack and then rebuild it when the app is resumed?

Comment: You have to hook into the lifecycle events of the app and respond to state changes (see [this example code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/services/lifecycle.dart) and [corresponding docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html)). When the app is ready to pause, save the state, e.g. using local storage, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369633/how-can-i-save-to-local-storage-using-flutter.

Comment: @raju-bitter: Why don't you write your comment as an answer? I think this would be the way to go.