# Importing a database using sqlite, flutter app

Tags: sqlite, flutter, mobile-application

My main goal is to import a database into a flutter app using sqlite(sqlflite plugin), instead of having to hard code all of the create tables into the apps code.

*I want the information to be accessed to the phone locally(access data from phone on airplane mode) that is why i am using sqlite

I am having trouble finding information on this online and was seeing if anyone had experience in doing this or has documentation/examples that could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for this : 
[Open an asset database](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md) in this case you must have the database already and you don't need to create tables

Comment: I am having trouble quite understanding that, it seems this would be a fix for something that i wouldn't have to otherwise write myself, i do have a mysql database with everything written in it, but for the purposes of this app i need the database to connect to sqlite to persist the specific data i need from the database to the app. Im starting to think that may not be possible.

Comment: you have a mysql and you want to import it to SQLITE ?

Comment: Yeah i do, i realize that i need to hardcode no matter what, unless i'm connecting remotely to a database which i don't want to do. Just need data to persist on the app permanently

Comment: take a look at other choice like Firebase firestore or Realm you get this behaviour for free

Comment: Perfect, looks like they have offline persistence, thank you!

Comment: yes also take a look at my answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369633/how-can-i-save-to-local-storage-using-flutter/50849802#50849802)

Comment: @Raouf Rahiche the link you provided no longer works, is there an updated link? I need this badly

Answer (score 0):

Flutter supports an open source module SQFlite. SQFlite is a way of storing app data in Flutter Application. SQFlite is a Database plugin for flutter. It is highly reliable and embedded Database engine. All the CRUD operation in the database will run on a background thread. You can see a simple example of this [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/07/flutter-sqlite-database-example.html).