# Using a Premade Database in Flutter(Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, flutter

I am working on a project using Android Studio that should be getting data from a sqlite database file. For this I am using the sqflite package, and I will have no need to update the database from the app.

I would like to know how I could incorporate my premade database file into this flutter app instead of relying on the onCreate method and placing SQL commands in my dart srouce.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you are looking for [this](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md) the idea is just to add it to your assets and load it

- also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51290278/4511702)

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks