# How to save to web local storage in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a web site built with **flutter for web** and currently, am trying to save to web local storage or cookie but can't seem to find any plugin or way to archive that.

Comment: Hi, I request you to share the solution here if this problem is solved @ikben

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save to local storage using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369633/how-to-save-to-local-storage-using-flutter)

Answer (score 30):

You can use `window.localStorage` from `dart:html`

```
import 'dart:html';

class IdRepository {
  final Storage _localStorage = window.localStorage;

  Future save(String id) async {
    _localStorage['selected_id'] = id;
  }

  Future<String> getId() async => _localStorage['selected_id'];

  Future invalidate() async {
    _localStorage.remove('selected_id');
  }
}
```

Comment: @dazza5000 No this does not work on flutter 1.9 check it yourself you will see that it does not

Answer (score 18):

`shared_preferences` dart package now supports local storage for the web from version [0.5.4.7+](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#0547)

Similar to shared preference on Android and iOS, the following is the code snippet for local storage on web

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart'; // rememeber to import shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+8


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        child: Text('Increment Counter'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}
```

Comment: For me the `SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();` never returns anything.

Comment: @EzPizza try adding an explicit dependency on `shared_preferences_web: ^0.1.2+7`

Answer (score 15):

I ran into a similar issue where my preferences **weren't being persisted across runs**.  I thought `window.localStorage` was broken.  I discovered that Flutter was simply launching with a **new port number** every time by default, so `window.localStorage` was getting wiped out.

This ticket talks about setting an explicit port.  This fixed my issue, and now `window.localStorage` persists across runs:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1769

In VS Code, you can set the port number in your `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "Flutter",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "dart",
    "args": ["--web-port", "8686"]
},
```

Answer (score 10):

With `flutter 1.10` we can use [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) package:

```dart
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';
// ...
// read preference
var myPref = window.localStorage['mypref'];
// ...
// write preference
window.localStorage['mypref'] = myPref;
```

Comment: Why use this over shared_preferences? pros/cons? As of 2023.

Answer (score 6):

I am using **[shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)** package to store data on local storage

```
class SessionManager {
  static SessionManager manager;
  static SharedPreferences _prefs;

  static Future<SessionManager> getInstance() async {
    if (manager == null || _prefs == null) {
      manager = SessionManager();
      _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    }
    return manager;
  }

  void putCityId(String cityId) {
    _prefs.setString("KEY_CITY_ID", cityId);
  }

  String getCityId() {
    return _prefs.getString("KEY_CITY_ID") ?? "";
  }
}
```

shared_preferences store data for the current session only.

If you want to store data permanently then you should use **cookie** to store data.

```
   import 'dart:html';
      
   class CookieManager {
      static CookieManager _manager;
    
      static getInstance() {
        if (_manager == null) {
          _manager = CookieManager();
        }
        return _manager;
      }
    
      void _addToCookie(String key, String value) {
        // 2592000 sec = 30 days.
        document.cookie = "$key=$value; max-age=2592000; path=/;";
      }
    
      String _getCookie(String key) {
        String cookies = document.cookie;
        List<String> listValues = cookies.isNotEmpty ? cookies.split(";") : List();
        String matchVal = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < listValues.length; i++) {
          List<String> map = listValues[i].split("=");
          String _key = map[0].trim();
          String _val = map[1].trim();
          if (key == _key) {
            matchVal = _val;
            break;
          }
        }
        return matchVal;
      }
    }
```

Comment: you are mistaken about **shared_preferences (web)** package, it stores data in `LocalStorage` not `SessionStorage`.

Comment: The cookie manager doesn't work for me. Do I need to configure anything in my browsers or store the cookie on the server side?

Comment: you should be using Hive: https://pub.dev/packages/hive, extremally fast!

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading to `flutter 1.9`, `'dart:html'` is not compiled anymore as it is not part of dart SDK that shipped with `Flutter`. 
We can use this package at the moment as it support Android, IOS and WEB:
[crypted_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/crypted_preferences)

Comment: Although, as someone wrote in slack, looks like It's still available, but there is a bug in the analyzer that make IDE show an error but if you run it it works.

Comment: This package requires a path. Anyone know what that is supposed to be?

Comment: It can be anything, this is just where it will save the data. You can see their example where they use:`Preferences.preferences(path: './example/prefs')`

Comment: Does this file need to exist? will it be created if it doesn't. If not what format does it need to be and what is the base of the path?

Comment: it will be created if not exist AFAIK. The `./` is the root of your project.