# Flutter For Web is there a way to store data?

Tags: web, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am building a web application with flutter for web, i know for sure that in the mobile version of flutter there is a way to store data in the device, but i don't know if this was even implemented in flutter for web yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save to web local storage in flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417667/how-to-save-to-web-local-storage-in-flutter-web)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin for storing and retrieving persistent simple data. They gave support for the web from version `0.5.4+7`

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you can use `localStorage`: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35116

Comment: Is this secure to store data like tokens to maintain the user logged in my application?

Comment: I don't think anything in the client side is secure. I think saving tokens should be fine.

Comment: In case someone comes here; It seems by answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417667/how-to-save-to-web-local-storage-in-flutter-web this no longer works

Answer (score 2):

**`Moor`** is a reactive persistence data storage library which is built on top of `sqlite` and is based on **indexedDb**. This library is compatible with most of web browsers.
You can use the package and see the documentation and example from [official link](https://pub.dev/packages/moor).

Comment: It seems that Moor is nowadays changed it's name to Drift. New link: https://pub.dev/packages/drift

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage from `dart:html` package but if your app also runs on mobile it is better to use [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) package which provide all the features of `dart:html`.

If your app has mobile support, dart compiler will yell at you with this at the time Im writing this answer,

> Avoid using web libraries, dart:html, dart:js and dart:js_util in
> Flutter packages that are not web plugins. These libraries are not
> supported outside a web context; functionality that depends on them
> will fail at runtime in Flutter mobile, and their use is generally
> discouraged in Flutter web.

Simple example with universal_html:

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';

void main() {
  String username = window.localStorage['username'];
  if (username == null) {
    window.localStorage['username'] = "dartyDev";
  } else {
    window.localStorage.remove('username');
  }
  // Get the latest updated value
  print(window.localStorage['username']);
}
```