# How to store data as a object in flutter without using shared preferences

Tags: flutter

**I want to local store in flutter app and access it in an app like shared preferences.**

I don't know how to store an object in flutter app;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking some information from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448527/10576762), some options to save to local storage are:

- Read and write files: https://flutter.io/reading-writing-files/
- SQLite via a [Flutter plugin](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite)
- SQLCipher via a [Flutter plugin](https://github.com/drydart/flutter_sqlcipher)
- SharedPreferences via a [Flutter plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/shared_preferences)
- [Firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)
- [Simple Embedded Application Store Database](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast)

Comment: hey, AbsoluteSpace thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted