# What to use to locally store data persistently in flutter?

Tags: json, database, flutter, dart

I am quite new to the programming environment so any help in which direction to head would be greatly appreciated. What should i use? NoSQL or Sql? What should be my deciding factors?

Should i go with a noSQL db like sembast since my server side application uses mongodb for storage and since i have to mainly deal with JSON data , or should I go with SQL db like sqflite? What should be my considerations when deciding between the two? Are there some other options that i should be aware of too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I save to local storage using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369633/how-can-i-save-to-local-storage-using-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SQL** databases are called relational databases. They are based on tables, which consists of a number of rows of data. They use SQL (Structured Query Language) for defining and manipulating the data. Thanks to this, SQL database are a good fit for complex querying. The transaction mechanism makes SQL databases a good choice for heavy duty transactional type applications.

**NoSQL** databases are called as non-relational or distributed database. They are based on key-value pairs document and don't have a standard schema definitions. Queries are focused on collection of documents so they cannot be very complicated. Although NoSQL provides transaction mechanism it's not stable enough for a complex transactional applications. NoSQL databases fit best for the hierarchical data storage (similar to JSON data) so they are highly preferred for large data set of data (big data).