# How to avoid re-fetching user info from Firebase with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

As soon as the user logs in my app redirects user to `homepage` and the `homepage` has a `bottomNavigationBar` and a `AppBar`

In this `AppBar` I display the user's **avatar** and the **appname**. To show this I use:

```
Stack(
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                future: getAvatar(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/default_avatar.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    );
                  }

                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return Center(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 45.0,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                            placeholder: 'assets/default_avatar.png',
                            image: snapshot.data['avatar'],
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }

                  return Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
```

It works great, but I do not find it is good practice... and every time I change page from the bottom navigation bar the avatar "reloads" (you see the `CircularProgressIndicator`). doesn't help that it is a stateful class

So my solution to stop this from happening is to save user data somewhere on the phone and just grab that information whenever I need it. **BUT HOW**

FYI, it is not only the avatar, I will display username and useremail. If anyone has an example that they can redirect me to, that would be great!

Thank you!

Comment: Storing data locally using flutter is already posted about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448527/8382028 Shared Preferences is probably the way to go

Comment: can you share this class full code ?

Comment: Why not use a StreamBuilder instead of FutureBuilder?

Comment: @Lee3 noob problems!

Comment: @Ants  been there brother! happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incorrectly using `FutureBuilder`.

The [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) state

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

You're clearly not doing that here as you are obtaining the `Future` during `build`, making it expected that any time that `build` is called you're seeing the loading indicator.

Obtain the `Future` in `initState` and pass that `Future` to your `FutureBuilder`.

However, if you're also using a `PageView` or equivalent to manage your pages, you'll also need to use the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and call `super.build(context)`.