# Flutter - How to save data locally?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a simple "dictionary" app to learn Flutter. The basic idea is that the user can add a word to his dictionary.

I have a class named Word (term, definition, examples in a list) but now I need to save the added words so the user can maintain them even when he closes the app.

I've heard about shared preferences and SQLite database but what would be the best approach in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save to local storage using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369633/how-to-save-to-local-storage-using-flutter)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**There are many packages for local storage in flutter**:

Here is some:

**1. [Shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)**

Flutter plugin for reading and writing simple key-value pairs. Wraps NSUserDefaults on iOS and SharedPreferences on Android.

**2. [Sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)**

Flutter plugin for SQLite, a self-contained, high-reliability, embedded, SQL database engine.

**3. [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)**

Lightweight and blazing fast key-value database written in pure Dart. Strongly encrypted using AES-256.

**4. [Sembast](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast)**

NoSQL persistent embedded file system document-based database for Dart VM and Flutter with encryption support.

**5. [Flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)**

Flutter Secure Storage provides API to store data in secure storage. Keychain is used in iOS, KeyStore based solution is used in Android.

**6. [Moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor)**
Moor is a safe and reactive persistence library for Dart applications

**7. [Floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor)**

The typesafe, reactive, and lightweight SQLite abstraction for your Flutter applications. This library is the runtime dependency.

**8. [Localstorage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage)**

Simple json file-based storage fo flutter. Alternative to react-native AsyncStorage

**9. [Objectbox](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox)**

ObjectBox is a super-fast NoSQL ACID compliant object database.

**10. [Json_store](https://pub.dev/packages/json_store)**

A Flutter storage solution somewhat similar to a browser's localStorage (but super powered)

Comment: any in-built solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can save data locally with third-part libraries so i mean packages, like a Sqflite, Shared Preferences, Hive etc.

In this case if you needn’t any picture or some data which can take more place and complex for save then you need to use Shared Preferences or Hive and etc.
But if you need to save something small, like a string, bool, etc then You should use  Sqflite so then sqflite would be best choise, because it easy to use and you can find more examples, tutorials about it.

Answer (score 0):

For some simple data storage like boolean/integer/string, shared_preferences is enough. For something more complex, I would go with Hive.

I wrote an [app](https://github.com/lomza/listview_cubit_hooks) and a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580) using cubits, hooks and Hive DB and it all worked fine together.