# How to save a List locally on users phone using flutter getStorage package

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a todo app and I want to save the todo List locally on users phone using getStorage package:

```
class Taskdata with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Task> _tasks = [];
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save to local storage using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369633/how-to-save-to-local-storage-using-flutter)